# How to train NER and integrate it into the original model using Spacy

Tags: model, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I am trying to train NER with my own data using Spacy. My question is how to integrate my trained NER into the **original** model ? so that it could be convenient to be continuously trained and used for my application. I did not find any sample.

I found some similar examples below to train NER, but it seems all of these don't save the trained model and integrate it back into Spacy. Some are hold in memory, some are save the NER model into additional folder... So how to do it in appropriate way to meet my demand ? Thank you !!!

I am using spacy 1.7.3

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner.py
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-dev-resources/blob/master/spacy-annotator/displacy/parse.py

Answer (score 3):

To provide training examples to the entity recogniser, you'll first need to create an instance of the GoldParse class. You can specify your annotations in a stand-off format or as token tags.

```
import spacy
import random
from spacy.gold import GoldParse
from spacy.language import EntityRecognizer

train_data = [
    ('Who is Chaka Khan?', [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]),
    ('I like London and Berlin.', [(7, 13, 'LOC'), (18, 24, 'LOC')])
]

nlp = spacy.load('en', entity=False, parser=False)
ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab, entity_types=['PERSON', 'LOC'])

for itn in range(5):
    random.shuffle(train_data)
    for raw_text, entity_offsets in train_data:
        doc = nlp.make_doc(raw_text)
        gold = GoldParse(doc, entities=entity_offsets)

        nlp.tagger(doc)
        ner.update(doc, gold)
ner.model.end_training()
```

to simplify this you can try this code

```
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, [u'rats', u'make', u'good', u'pets'])
gold = GoldParse(doc, [u'U-ANIMAL', u'O', u'O', u'O'])
ner = EntityRecognizer(nlp.vocab, entity_types=['ANIMAL'])
ner.update(doc, gold)
```

https://spacy.io/docs/usage/training-ner

Answer (score 1):

spaCy documentation discusses how to update a pre-existing model here: https://spacy.io/docs/usage/training-ner

Haven't done this myself so not sure if it's easy to do/follow but it seems like a good place to start, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a late addition, but I had this same question when I stumbled across this post and happened to find the answer. Basically, just set your nlp value to the directory your training model is located:

```
nlp = spacy.load('/model')
```